# Fourier inversion theorem for probability measures on Banach spaces

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, fourier-analysis, stochastic-analysis

Is there an analogue of the [Fourier inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_inversion_theorem) to Banach spaces?

To be precise, if $\mu$ is a measure on a $\mathbb R$-Banach space $E$ and $f\in\mathcal L^1(\mu)$, the "Fourier transform" of $f$ with respect to $\mu$ could be defined as $$(\mathcal F_\mu f)(\varphi):=\int\mu({\rm d}x)e^{-{\rm i}\varphi(x)}f(x)\;\;\;\text{for }\varphi\in E'.$$ Analogously, if $\nu$ is a finite measure on $E$, we could define the "Fourier transform" of $\nu$ by $$(\hat\nu)(\varphi):=(\mathcal F_\nu1)(\varphi)=\int\nu({\rm d}x)e^{-{\rm i}\varphi(x)}\;\;\;\text{for }\varphi\in E'.$$

Maybe [Bochner's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner%27s_theorem#The_theorem_for_locally_compact_abelian_groups) is related to this question.

Moreover, observe that if $E$ is a $\mathbb R$-Hilbert space $H$, $\mu$ is a measure on $H$, $f\in\mathcal L^1(\mu;E)$ and $\lambda$ is a finite measure on $H$, then $$\int\mathcal F_\mu f\:{\rm d}\lambda=\int f\hat\lambda\:{\rm d}\mu;\tag1$$ for whatever this might be useful.

Comment: I think you'd need a way of finding a measure $\mu^*$ on $E$ such that the formal identity $\int_{E'} e^{-i\varphi(x)}\textrm{d}\mu^*(\varphi)=\delta_{x}$ holds (in some weak sense). Indeed, for $E'=\mathbb{R}^d$, the Lesbegue measure has exactly this property and it is ultimately what drives the proof of the Fourier Inversion Theorem.

Comment: Whoops... a measure $\mu^*$ on $E'$ of course.